# Update selectInput() by exlcluding values selected from another selectInput()

Tags: r, shiny

In the `shiny` app below I want the selected values of the 1st `selectInput()` to be excluded from the 2nd `selectInput()` plus the one column I already exclude.

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectInput("col","Pick a column to change its name",
                choices = colnames(iris)[-c(1)]),
    uiOutput("second")
    
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
output$second<-renderUI({
  selectInput("col2","Pick a column to change its name",
              choices = colnames(iris)[-c(1,input$col)])
})
 
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try to remove names in two steps

```r
output$second<-renderUI({
  ex_names <- colnames(iris)[-1]
  ex_names <- ex_names[! ex_names %in% input$col]
  selectInput("col2","Pick a column to change its name", choices = ex_names)
})
```

Comment: plz check here as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71652550/update-updateselectinput-based-on-values-of-another-updateselectinput

Comment: I swear I didn't check that answer before, haha

Comment: Actually, maybe someone "borrowed" my answer. My answer time is earlier than that one.

Comment: your opinion on this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71758678/update-dataframe-based-on-shiny-widgets-inputs