# Update dataframe based on shiny widgets' inputs

Tags: r, shiny

Im trying to create a dataframe which will update its values based on the `shiny` widgets selections in the sidebar. But the datatable I use to check this does not seem to display all column names and cell values .

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

### user inter phase
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  ### App title ----
  
  
  titlePanel(title=div(img(src="pics/IRP_NHSc.jpg", width="99%")))
  ,
  
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      ### Input files ----
      selectInput("Price","Select the price for analysis", c("List price","End consumer price without VAT", "End consumer price with VAT", "Reimbursed price"),multiple = T),     
      selectInput("IRP_A","Select IRP formula", c("Price average"="PA","Median price"="MP","3 lowest price average"="3L", "Lowest price"="LP",  "Turkish rule"="TR", "Swiss rule"="SR" )),
      
      
      # Input: Slider for the number of bins ----
      sliderInput(inputId = "increase",
                  label = "% increase",
                  min = -20,
                  max = 100,
                  value = 35), width = 2,
      
    ),
    
    ### Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    
    mainPanel(
      
      tabsetPanel(
        
        tabPanel("Export report", 
                 dataTableOutput("tab7"))
        
      )
      
    )
  )
)


#### Server 
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
output$tab7<-renderDataTable({
  Price<-input$Price
  IRP<-input$IRP_A
  Per<-input$increase
  df<-as.data.frame(Price,IRP,Per)
})
  
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you want to see but I think as.data.frame is taking only the first object as the thing to convert into a data frame and the second as the row name. If you put them in a list you can see all the inputs in the table:

df<-as.data.frame(list('price' = Price, 'irp' = IRP,'per' = Per))

(although it does give an error until you select at least one price)